# How do I get the values of a deleted range in Excel VSTO C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

[Sheet Change Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange)

The Target Range refers to the range values referred to by the address of the deleted row. I need the Range values that were just deleted. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In _Application_SheetActivate

```
dataArray = ((Excel.Worksheet)Sh).UsedRange.Value2;
```

In Application_SheetChange(object Sh, Excel.Range Target)

```
var deletedRow = _dataArray.ToJaggedArray();
var values = deletedRow[Target.Row - 1];
```

```
        public static object[][] ToJaggedArray(this object[,] array)
        {
            object[][] jagged = new object[array.GetLength(0)][];

            for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                jagged[i] = new object[array.GetLength(1)];
                for (int j = 1; j <= array.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    jagged[i][j - 1] = array[i + 1, j];
                }
            }

            return jagged;
        }
```